# Error printing out an element in an array

Tags: c

I'm trying to print out an element in my array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char greeting[6] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
    printf("%s", greeting[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect it to print out `H`, but instead it crashed and the Windows dialog popped up:

> "program.exe has stopped working"

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try `printf("%s", &greeting[1]);`: it should print "ello".

Comment: You clarified the original question: use  "%s" to print a string, use "c%" to print a character. Use "%d" or "0x%02x" to print the ASCII representation of the character).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `printf("%s", &greeting[1]);` it should print "ello":

1) "greeting" is a character array containing the string "Hello\0".

2) You can call `printf("%s\n", greeting);` with no problem.

3) "greeting[0]" is the first *character* in the array.
   "&greeting[0]" is a pointer to the first character in the array.

`printf("%s", s)` expects s to be a pointer, not a character.

4) Alternatively, you might *want* to print just a character.
   In this case, try `printf("%c", greeting[0]);`

5) Use `"%s"` to print a string, use `"c%"` to print a character. Use `"%d"` or `"0x%02x"`to print the ASCII representation of the character.
'Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

You should write

```
printf("%c", greeting[1]);
```

to write out a single character (`'H'`) instead of trying to print a string. Your program crashes because `%s` expects a `char*` parameter to be passed, but `greeting[1]` is of type `char`.

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
printf("%c \n", greeting[1]);
```

The format specifier to print a char is `c`. So the format string to be used is `%c`.